# Confused with Pointer Reference and Pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I am trying to create one singly linked list and swap two `int` element in sub-
function.

1. in function `swap(int *a,int *b)` , the type of parameter is `int *`,and it can work successfully.
2. in function `build_sll(node *head)`, the singly linked list won't be created successfully.
3. Once I set the type of parameter to be `build_sll(node *&head)`,and it will be created singly linked list successfully.

Confused with:

function `swap(int *a,int *b)` passed the *address* of `a` `b`, I could modify the value of `a` `b` .
 function `build_sll(node *head)` passed only the *value* of pointer `head`. I could not modify the value of `head`.
why here does not pass the *address* of `head`. The only difference between them is their data type.

while set `build_sll(node *head)`, after `GDB` my code, and I found that all the `node` object have been created successfully. In `main` if I visited the allocated address, it does record the `node` information. how to delete memory in such case.

See my code to make clear my question.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<memory.h>

using namespace std;

typedef struct node{
    int num;
    struct node * next;

    node(int num,struct node * next)
    {
        this->num = num;
        this->next = next;
    }

}node;

void build_sll(node *&head);
void del_memory(node *&head);
void travel_sll(node *head);
void swap(int *,int *);

int main()
{
   int a =10 ,b = 5; 
   node *head = NULL;

    build_sll(head);
    travel_sll(head);
    del_memory(head);

    swap(&a,&b);
    cout << a <<"  "<< b <<"\n";

    exit(0);
}

void build_sll(node *&head)
{
    head = new node(0,NULL);
    node * tail = head;

    for(int index = 1 ; index < 8;index++)
    {
         node * temp = new node(index,NULL);
         tail -> next = temp;
         tail = temp;
    }
}

void travel_sll(node *head)
{
    if(head)
    {
        head = head -> next;
        while(head)
        {
            cout << head->num <<"\n";
            head = head -> next ;
        }
    }
}

void del_memory(node *&head)
{
    delete [] head;
}

void swap(int *a,int *b)
{
    int t;
    t = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = t;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> function `swap(int *a,int *b)` passed the address of a b, I could modify the value of a b . function `build_sll(node *head)` passed only the value of pointer head. I could not modify the value of head. why here does not pass the address of head. The only difference between them is their data type.

In function `swap`, you want to modify/access the value of `int` so passing `int *` or `int &` would work. Passing arguments of type `int` is good for reading the value of arguments, but if you change it, only local copy is updated and not the values with which you called the function.

In function  `build_sll` you want to change the argument of type `node *`. So you should pass argument of type `node **` or `node *&` to ensure you can change the value with with it was called. Passing `node *` would only change the local copy (in called function) and original value in the callee function would remain unchanged.

Your options are:

- Preferable `node * build_sll(node *);`
- OK `node * build_sll(node *&);`
- Avoid this: `node * build_sll(node **);` etc

Comment: The preferable option wouldn't work in this case because OP wants to modify the pointer passed, not the data pointed by it :)

Comment: @Rakete1111 it works just fine. OP can (and should) modify the pointer outside the function. Although, the answer doesn't really hold the readers hand and tell how to use the return value :)

Comment: But in `build_sll` OP calls `head = new node(0,NULL);`, and if `head` is passed by value, it won't change the passed pointer.

Comment: @Rakete1111 I wrote about high level design of the function. Implementation in all 3 cases would be more or less different.

Answer (score 1):

> function swap(int *a,int *b) passed the address of a b, I could modify the value of a b . function build_sll(node *head) passed only the value of pointer head. I could not modify the value of head. why here does not pass the address of head. The only difference between them is their data type.

Well:

```
swap(&a,&b);
```

Here you're passing the address of a, and of b - that is, you're constructing pointers which point at the values that `a` and `b` refer to, and passing those pointers as arguments to the `swap` function.

```
build_sll(head);
```

Here you're passing the *value* of head (which happens to be a pointer variable). The value passed points at *something* (or is null), but it doesn't point at the value that `head` itself refers to..

If you look inside `build_s11`, assuming it was declared to receive a `node *` parameter:

```
void build_sll(node *head)
{
    head = new node(0,NULL);
```

Then you'll not that the parameter is also called `head` - but this is coincidental. **What it does mean is that assignment is just changing the value of the parameter variable, not of the original variable. That is, `head` inside `build_s11` is a *different* variable to `head` in the calling expression; there are two variables, and you are modifying the one inside the function, but not the one in the caller**.

So why doesn't it behave the same way in `swap`? Well, the fundamental difference is that in `build_s11` you are assigning to the parameter variable itself, whereas in `swap` you are assigning to the pointer target:

```
*a = *b;
```

If you wanted to see consistent behaviour, you should use consistent syntax. `build_s11` could be declared as:

```
void build_sll(node **head);
```

and you would call it as:

```
build_sll(&head);
```

... and then you could change the value of of a passed-by-pointer `node *` value by assinging to `*head`:

```
void build_sll(node **head)
{
    *head = new node(0,NULL);
    node * tail = *head;
```

... etc. Note that it is now consistent: just as in `swap` you used `*a` and `*b` (rather than plain `a` and `b`), you are now using `*head` in `build_s11` (rather than `head`).

Of course you can also use a reference, as you have done in your full code posting.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the first question correctly, you're confused why you can modify the values of `a` and `b` through pointers, and can't modify the value of `head` through the same syntax.

If this is the case, this happens because the type of `a` and `b` is `int`, and `int *a` points to the address of the variable in memory, thus enabling you to modify in the function through dereference. You could implement the `swap` function like this:

```
void swap(int &a,int &b)
{
    int t;
    t = a;
    a = b;
    b = t;
}
```

and `swap(a,b)` would work.

As you correctly noticed, the datatype of `head` is different, it's `node *`. To modify it's value you need a pointer to the memory address, where pointer itself is stored. Thus, you need to pass a reference to the `node *head` to modify it. `build_sll` function could be implemented with dereferences too

```
void build_sll(node **head)
{
    *head = new node(0,NULL);
    node * tail = head;

    for(int index = 1 ; index < 8;index++)
    {
         node * temp = new node(index,NULL);
         tail -> next = temp;
         tail = temp;
    }
}
```

However, the syntax with double pointers is not preferred, as it leads to using dereferences constantly, so it's better to use a `&` syntax